# Indexed, not submitted in sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, jekyll

I set my sitemap frequency to weekly, but still the following URL is showing as "not submitted in sitemap."
This issue started only for new URLs from this month.

I don't know what happened?

[image]

Comment: Two things to double check if you haven't already: 1) that the urls are properly listed in the final generated sitemap file, and 2) that the [sitemaps report](https://search.google.com/search-console/sitemaps) doesn't show any issues with the sitemap file.

Comment: Yes, I have already verified these two things.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency you set is a requested recommendation. Indexers do not guarantee to crawl your site if they feel they know better (i.e. low traffic, infrequent updates will result in less frequent crawls).

"Indexed, not submitted in index" usually means that the page was found via a crawl and has been indexed but wasn't found in the version of the sitemap the indexer has on file. This might be because your sitemap wasn't re-crawled at the same time as the page linking to your new content.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?, My sitemap is created properly and Im able to see the URL.

Comment: There is no need to "fix" it.   Sitemaps are not really important for anything.  They don't help SEO.   Unless you want to see stats about the URLs how many URLs from that particular sitemap are indexed, there is really no point in even having one.   Because Googlebot can crawl your site, your sitemap is unnecessary.   In any case, this will fix itself.  Google seems to need about 6 months to get the sitemap data in order on their end.